# How to access routerlink without parameters in Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, routes

I struggle accessing a routerlink without its parameters in Angular 2. I need the routerlinks to check if I want to display a certain element in my navigation. I do this like this for normal routerlinks without parameters:

```
*ngIf="router.url === '/about'"
```

Now I have links with parameters like `/link/category` with category being a parameter and I would like to check if the routerlink is `/link/*`. How do I do this best?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the url, if it contains '`link`', then evaluate it to `true`.

Something like:

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
route;
constructor(router: Router) { 

      router.events.subscribe((url:any) => this.route = url);
      //  this.router = "link/category" or something else...

}
checkRoute() {
   return this.route.includes('link');
   //will return true if this.route has 'link' in it,
   //otherwise it will return false.
}
```

and then just use *ngIf='checkRoute()' to see if the route you are in contains `'link'`

Comment: perfect the `.includes()` function was exactly what I was searching for the last hour. many thanks!